# Wildfly not providing JSF implementation?

Tags: jsf, wildfly

I´m just starting with JSF and Wildfly and I am facing a strange error. Following an excellent tutorial from BalusC (https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html) I arrived to the part where I have to run for first time the JSF project on Wildfly, but it fail, with an error which suggest Wildfly is not providing JSF implementation at all. Next is the stacktrace. Any help will very appreciate.

```
21:45:48,684 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."project-jsf-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."project-jsf-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet from [Module "deployment.project-jsf-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1075)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:276)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet from [Module "deployment.project-jsf-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
```

Comment: WildFly is definitely supplying a JSF implementation. How are you booting WildFly?

Comment: Yes, I know Wildfly is a JEE implementation and this is why I am lost. My project is a Maven projec here you have the only dependenciy I have in my POM:     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>and  I just add Wildfly as a Server into Eclipse. So, I boot it just pressing the green button

Comment: WildFly is currently downloadable as "Jakarta EE Full & Web Distribution" and "WildFly Preview EE 9 Distribution". The tutorial is written for "Jakarta EE Full & Web Distribution" only (the other uses `jakarta.*` package name instead of `javax.*`). Which one exactly did you pick? The symptoms so far suggest that you picked the preview.

Comment: I BalusC, many thanks for your time. You are totally right. That was the cause. If you warned about this in your tutorial, sorry, I didn't pay enough attention. In other case will be good to add a warning. Many thanks again and thank you for your excellent tutorial!

Answer (score 9):

WildFly is currently downloadable as "*Jakarta EE Full & Web Distribution*" and "*WildFly Preview EE 9 Distribution*". The tutorial is written for "*Jakarta EE Full & Web Distribution*" only. The "*WildFly Preview EE 9 Distribution*" one uses `jakarta.*` package name instead of `javax.*` package.

The "[Installing WildFly](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html#InstallingWildFly)" section has been updated. Previously it said

> WildFly is an open source Jakarta EE application server from Red Hat. You can download it from wildfly.org. Make sure you choose the “Java EE Full & Web Distribution" download and not, for example, the “Servlet-Only Distribution”.

It has now been updated to

> WildFly is an open source Jakarta EE application server from Red Hat. You can download it from wildfly.org. Make sure you choose the “Jakarta EE Full & Web Distribution" download and not, for example, the “WildFly Preview EE 9 Distribution” or “Servlet-Only Distribution”.

Noted should be that "*WildFly Preview EE 9 Distribution*" can safely be used as long as you keep in mind to manually swap out `javax.*` for `jakarta.*` over all place in the tutorial.